# how can i call one function inside of another?

Tags: python, function, dice

I just want to make a separate function in the dice class which would allow me to store every 'roll' in the list_of_rolls list in the 'rolls' function. so when 'rolls' is called it would display a list of every 'roll' executed (if any).

I tried using global but it didn't work (maybe i did it wrong), i also heard using global is a bad habit so if there is another way i wouldn't mind. my indents are proper it is just not shown here.

```
import random


class Dice:

    def roll(self):
        x = random.randint(1, 6)
        y = random.randint(1, 6)
        roll_list = (x, y)
        return roll_list

    def rolls(self):
        list_of_rolls = []
        final = list_of_rolls.append()
        return final
```

Comment: i want the rolls function to declare all rolls from the past as well so if i ran the code and twice it would show all the rolls from both of the code runs. not just the present run. i've been trying for a few hours but i can't figure it out. so `list_of_rolls` would accumulate every `roll` that was run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this. However I am just going to suggest the most straight forward way which is to use text file to store your history of rolls within the Dice class itself.
Note that the con will be **multiple instances of Dice will be accessing the same history file**
However this implementation may not be optimized, as everytime you roll a dice you are opening the file and appending new rolls to it. It may not be ideal if you need millions of rolls. That say I will leave it to you to better/optimize the solution.

```
import random

class Dice:
    list_of_rolls = []
    filename = "./roll_history.txt" # a textfile to store history of rolls

def __init__(self):
    try: # just to check if file exists if not create one for storing
        file = open(self.filename, "r")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found")
        file = open(self.filename, "x") #creates file
    finally:
        file.close()

    with open(self.filename, 'r') as opened_file_object:
        self.list_of_rolls = opened_file_object.read().splitlines()
    print(self.list_of_rolls)

def roll(self):
    x = random.randint(1, 6)
    y = random.randint(1, 6)
    roll_list = (x, y)
    self.list_of_rolls.append(roll_list) # updates the array with latest roll
    file = open(self.filename, 'a') # 'a' for appending new rolls
    # I append a newline so that the rolls are more readable in the text file
    file.write('(' + str(x) + ',' + str(y) + ')\n') # appends a newline
    return roll_list

def rolls(self):
    return self.list_of_rolls

print(Dice().roll()) # append 2 dice rolls here
print(Dice().roll())
print(Dice().rolls()) # you should see 2 dice rolls here
```

## try closing your python program and run it again,

```
Dice() # you should be able to see past rolls
```

Comment: this is almost what i wanted but i've been trying and am still stumped. i want the rolls function to declare all rolls from the past as well so if i ran the code and twice it would show all the rolls from both of the code runs. in the solution you gave me (i am thankful) it resets everytime i run the code.

Comment: Let me clarify this...you want your program to run a few dice rolls, store them then close the program. The next time you run the program and you use rolls() it returns all the previous dice rolls?

Answer (score 0):

Declare list_of_rolls as member variable of the class instead of defining it in the function. Create a constructor to initialize it. If you do it after class name than it becomes for the class and not at instance level.

```
import random
class Dice:
    # list_of_rolls = [] # becomes class variable and dont use it

    def __init__(self):
         self.list_of_rolls = []        

    def roll(self):
```